# Cannot alter webView url with should startLoadWithRequest - white screen instead

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I try to alter url in `UIViewWeb`. What I want to do is to append a string to url of each request.

So my code is following

```
var url = "http://www.url.com" 
var param = "?my_param=true" 

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if request.url?.absoluteString.contains(param) == false {
        if request.url?.absoluteString.contains(url) == false {
            guard let urlWithParam = URL(string: url + param) else { return true }
            let requestWithParam = URLRequest(url: urlWithParam)
            webView.loadRequest(requestWithParam)
            guard let result = webView.delegate?.webView!(webView, shouldStartLoadWith: requestWithParam, navigationType: navigationType) else { return false }
            return result
        } else {
            guard let initialRequestURL = request.url?.absoluteString else { return true }
            guard let urlWithParam = URL(string: initialRequestURL + param) else { return true }
            let requestWithParam = URLRequest(url: urlWithParam)
            webView.loadRequest(requestWithParam)
            guard let result = webView.delegate?.webView!(webView, shouldStartLoadWith: requestWithParam, navigationType: navigationType) else { return false }
            return result
        }

    } else {
        print("request.url?.absoluteString doesnt contain webViewParam")
        return true
    }
}
```

What I have in my webView is white screen and infinite printing to console of

> request.url?.absoluteString doesnt contain webViewParam

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should return false when the error printed, if you return true, it will try to load again thus getting loop

Comment: That fixed the loop, but screen is still blank :(

Comment: try print the url before return false, see if its valid url or not